# Preciso alterar e manter a cor de background de um link ao clicar nele

Tags: html, css

Estou tentando aprender HTML e CSS e me deparei com esse problema: Preciso que a cor de fundo do link fique conforme a imagem: [Imagem modelo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XMOg.png), mesmo após eu clicar em outro elemento fora da nav
. Já tentei usar algumas pseudo-classes do CSS pra fazer isso, mas quando eu clico fora da nav a cor de fundo do link volta a anterior.

```html
         <nav class="nav-group">
            <h5 class="nav-group-title">Opções</h5>
            <a href="#!cadastro" class="nav-group-item" id="Cadastro">
              <span class="icon icon-user-add"></span>
              Cadastrar Funcionários
            </a>
            <a href="#!cadastroProd" class="nav-group-item" id="CadProd">
              <span class="icon icon-bag"></span>
              Cadastrar Produtos
            </a>
            <a href="#!listarProd" class="nav-group-item" id="ListProd">
              <span class="icon icon-doc-text"></span>
              Listar produtos
            </a>
            <a href="#!status" class="nav-group-item" id="Status">
              <span class="icon icon-retweet"></span>
              Status de funcionamento
            </a>
            <a href="#!calcular" class="nav-group-item" id="Calcular">
              <span class="icon icon-chart-bar"></span>
              Calcular comissão
            </a>
            <a href="#!removeFunc" class="nav-group-item" id="RemoveFunc">
              <span class="icon icon-attention"></span>
              Remover funcionário
            </a>
          </nav>
```

```css
      .nav-group {
       font-size: 14px;
      }

      .nav-group-item {
       padding: 2px 10px 2px 25px;
       display: block;
       color: #333;
       text-decoration: none;
       white-space: nowrap;
       overflow: hidden;
       text-overflow: ellipsis;
     }

     a.nav-group-item:hover{
        background-color: #dbeaf1;
     }

     a.nav-group-item:focus{
        background-color: #c9cbcc;
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode alterar o css desse link com um javascript ou JQuery (mais simples):

```
$('#Cadastro')on('click', function(){
    $(this).css('background-color', '#C9CBCC');
});
```

#C9CBCC é a cor do background exata do seu print no item "Cadastrar Funcionários".

com JQuery você vai poder brincar de dar efeito de forma simples (cuidado com a carga, embora depois vai cachear no navegador)!

Answer (score 0):

Voce tem que definir um background para quando o link estiver ativo, usa esse.

a:active {
background-color: yellow;
}

Comment: Já tentei dessa forma porém, não funcionou para esse caso, isso apenas mudou a cor no momento que eu cliquei e logo depois voltou a anterior.